# King of Tokyo: Damage dealt on first entry in to Tokyo

Tags: king-of-tokyo

I've looked around SE and can't seem to find an answer to this specific question.
I recognize that a new version of KOT is out that redefines how Tokyo is entered; this question is regarding the old version where a (claw) must be rolled to enter.

The [rule book](http://www.iellogames.com/downloads/KOT_rules.pdf) states "If Tokyo is unoccupied, the first
Monster to obtain at least one (claw) gets the control of Tokyo and places his figure in Tokyo *without dealing any damage*."

Is that to say that all (claw) rolls do not deal damage? Or only the first (claw) does not do damage, and the remainder can be dealt to those outside Tokyo?

I'm under the impression that damage cannot be dealt at all if you are the first to enter Tokyo, but discussions elsewhere have called it in to question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the second edition change? I'm pretty sure the rules are exactly the same in functionality; just with clearer wordings.

Comment: @Gendolkari, See [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/33626/2880) from last week.

Comment: Thanks. But man that seems like a bad rule change. Previously there was some strategy to going for or avoiding smash rolls based on your preference to enter Tokyo or not. With the new rules, the first player has very little meaningful choice. If he's going to automatically enter Tokyo no matter what, it would make more sense just to start him there automatically.

Comment: @GendoIkari I somewhat agree with you. But at least this way if you have first turn, you can focus on rolling energy or stars instead of rolling smashes since you know you're going in (and therefore get the star for taking Tokyo)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Damage rolled outside of Tokyo is dealt to those in Tokyo.

> Each [Claw] results in a point of damage dealt to Monsters who are not in the same place as you.
>
> - *If you are in Tokyo (Tokyo City or Tokyo Bay)* when you get [Claw], you deal damage to all the Monsters who are not in Tokyo.
> - *If you are outside Tokyo* when you get [Claw], you deal damage to
>   all the Monsters who are in Tokyo (Tokyo City or Tokyo Bay).

Note that it's your location when you get the Claw result that counts, so your location before any moves. There's nothing to support dealing Claw dice damage to those in the same zone as you started.

The passage you quoted simply reminds you of the above. It also instructs you that dealing damage to noone is not dealing damage at all, which may matter for some Item cards.

Answer (score 3):

The rules are referring to the first ***instance*** of damage, regardless of how much it is for.  If you were to deal any amount of damage to an empty Tokyo, ***you deal no damage and then enter Tokyo***.  The damage does not overflow to other characters, as you're not considered to be inside Tokyo until after the entire attack.  In order to deal damage from Tokyo with a roll, you'll have to do so on a subsequent turn.

Keep in mind that ***players outside of Tokyo cannot attack each other***.  Players outside Tokyo only damage the player inside Tokyo (if any), and a player inside Tokyo damages (all) players outside.